# problem with dropdownlist updateprogress and updatepanel

Tags: asp.net, ajax, drop-down-menu, updatepanel, updateprogress

The updateprogress doesnt show the gif. If the dropdownlist is inside updatepanel without trigger, it works. Any idea?

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" DisplayAfter="0">
        <ProgressTemplate>
            <div id="IMGDIV" align="center" valign="middle" runat="server" style="position: absolute;left: 52%;top: 61%;visibility:visible;vertical-align:middle; background-color:Transparent">
                <img src="../App_Themes/Default/images/27-1.gif" />
            </div>
        </ProgressTemplate>            
    </asp:UpdateProgress>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <cc1:Chartlet ID="Chartlet1" runat="server" />
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DropDownList1" EventName="selectedindexchanged" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 5):

By Design External triggers for an UpdatePanel do not fire an associated UpdateProgress, since the implementation of enabling the UpdateProgress control searches the control hierarchy for the calling control; an external trigger will not be present in the control hierarchy.

I found the answer here: [Updateprogessbar is not working when Setting AssociatedUpdatePanelID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187953/updateprogessbar-is-not-working-when-setting-associatedupdatepanelid).

So I had just to delete: AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1"

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

Just remove the following property from your `UpdateProgress`:
`AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1"`

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are not talking about "gif animation". If you are using IE, it has problems in animating the gifs which are specified at aspx/ascx at design time.  I use a [plugin like blockUI](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/), which adds the gif at run time